# Google Maps not panning to my map Center

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a map with a center that I've set – and when I ask the map to return the center, it returns the same values. However the map is zooming in on the only pin I have at the moment.

I want the map to zoom out to the same place, no matter where the pins are.

Context: the map lists locations in a country. At the moment there is only one, but I want the map to zoom out to show the entire country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify the country in setCenter of google maps because it will always focus on the specific coordinates. 
If you want the zoom to center a country, you will have a database of country boundaries (as coordinates) used together with fitBounds and [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds).

Here is a sample code in using bounds where latLngList should be the coordinates loaded from a country

```
var LatLngList = new Array (new google.maps.LatLng (52.537,-2.061), new google.maps.LatLng (52.564,-2.017));
//  Create a new viewpoint bound
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
//  Go through each...
for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
  //  And increase the bounds to take this point
  bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
}
//  Fit these bounds to the map
map.fitBounds (bounds);
```

reference: [Zoom to Fit all markers](http://blog.shamess.info/2009/09/29/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-maps-api-v3/)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't shared any code I'm guessing you are doing something like this.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
bounds.extend (LATLNG);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

This will add all points to the bounds and ensure that the zoom level is such to accommodate all the points. In your case it would zoom on the lone point you have.

If you want to zoom on a country but don't have the coordinates you could get them by using geocoding;

```
var address = "India"; // THE COUNTRY / ADDRESS WILL COME HERE
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);results[0].geometry.location,map: map,icon:getGoogleIcon('purple')});
      } else {
        alert(address + " not found");
      }
    });
```

It will set the bounds to the address you provide.